# Is there a Framework that allows you write "real" classes using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a Framework that allows you to define classes like this?
If not a Framework, any workaround to get this type of syntax?

```
class Car 
{
    var speed = 122; 
    var model = "Nissan Z";

    function drive() 
    {
       return doStuffToDrive();
    }
}

var car = new Car();
car.drive();
```

Or is this the closest you can get with Javascript?

```
var car = {
    speed: 122,
    model: "nissan Z",
    drive: function () {
        return doStuffToDrive();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many languages on top of Javascript which just compile down to Javascript in the end, many of them adding a class-like syntax. For example: http://coffeescript.org

Comment: Coffeescript is what you are looking for.

Comment: But why is it you are very specific about the syntax sugar? What problem is it solving for you?

Comment: For the same reason its nice to have javascript running with the same syntax on the backend and the frontend using nodejs, its nice to run similar syntax using php too.

Comment: So my suspicion was correct: Your question boils down to *"How can I make JavaScript behave more like PHP?"* That's the wrong question to ask. JavaScript is not PHP, not even close. You are making things hard on yourself by trying to hide away integral parts of a language behind a thick coating of syntactic sugar. My suggestion would be to learn how JS works first, so you can consciously assess whether any of those frameworks or tools suggested below *actually do anything for you*.

Comment: If you want to use class syntax but don’t want to wait for ES6, there's nothing wrong with it.Downvoting the question won't change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has a syntax which is very similar to what you have asked.

From the blog post of John Papa (http://bit.ly/1E8qC6E), here is a sample class in TypeScript -

```
class Car {

  engine: string;

  constructor (engine: string) {

      this.engine = engine;

  }


  start() {

      return "Started " + this.engine;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

## The Built-in Way of Today

```
var Car = function(opts) {
 // This is your constructor.
 this.model = opts.model;
 this.speed = opts.speed;
};

// Instance methods. By declaring them here instead of inside the ctor,
// you only have one instance of the function, called by multiple instances of
// cars, but with the car instance as the ´this´ context.
Car.prototype.drive = function() {
  console.log(this.model);
  console.log(this.speed);
};

// And creating an instance:
var car = new MyCar({
  model: 'Nissan Z',
  speed: 122
});

car.drive();
```

## Frameworks

There are too many frameworks to mention; [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is one, and has this, and a few other things.

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
  speed: 122, // default value
  model: "Nissan Z", // default value
  // Not *really* the constructor, but used as such by Backbone
  // so it can work its magic.
  initialize: function(opts) {
    this.model = opts.model;
    this.speed = opts.speed;
  },
  drive: function() {
    // Note the use of 'this'
    console.log(this.model, ' is driving', this.speed);
  }
});

// And create an instance
var car = new MyCar({
  model: 'Porsche Cayman S',
  speed: 1337
});
```

## Compile-To-JavaScript (ES5)

Again, there are many contenders.

- CoffeeScript (an entirely different syntax)
- TypeScript (same syntax, with additional features such as static typing)
- Spider (diff. syntax)
- ES6 / Harmony (the next version of JavaScript), but you will need a tool called a transpiler. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is excellent.

## The Bult-in Way of Tomorrow (ES6)

```
class Car {
   constructor(opts) {
      this.model = opts.model;
      this.speed = opts.speed;
   }
   drive() {
     console.log(this.model);
     console.log(this.speed);
   }
}

// instance of car
var car = new Car();
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are included in EcmaScript 6 specification, which you can already use today with the help of transpiler such as [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) (formerly known as 6to5) or [es6-class](https://github.com/esnext/es6-class).

Here's some ES6 Class syntax (from Babel learning page)

```
  class SkinnedMesh extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor(geometry, materials) {
    super(geometry, materials);

    this.idMatrix = SkinnedMesh.defaultMatrix();
    this.bones = [];
    this.boneMatrices = [];
    //...
  }
  update(camera) {
    //...
    super.update();
  }
  static defaultMatrix() {
    return new THREE.Matrix4();
  }
}
```

You can also use something like [SweetJS](http://sweetjs.org) to define a macro for the class syntax (as is it defined on the homepage):

```
// Define the class macro here...
macro class {

  rule {

    $className {
        constructor $cparams $cbody
        $($mname $mparams $mbody) ...
    }

  } => {

    function $className $cparams $cbody

    $($className.prototype.$mname
      = function $mname $mparams $mbody; ) ...

  }

}

// And now classes are in JavaScript!
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  say(msg) {
    console.log(this.name + " says: " + msg);
  }
}
var bob = new Person("Bob");
bob.say("Macros are sweet!");
```

Comment: wow that sweetjs solution is incredibly neat!.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the built-in way not good enough for you?

```
function Car() {
    this.speed = 122; 
    this.model = "Nissan Z";
    this.drive = function () {
       return doStuffToDrive();
    }
}

var car = new Car();
car.drive();

console.log(typeof car)          // "object"
console.log(car instanceof Car)  // true
```

Comment: because it makes it impossible to differentiate between classes and functions inside of your source, its a workaround for the lack of classes in Javascript that makes the code less readable

Comment: *Everything* is an object in JavaScript. Even functions are objects. There are no classes. There is no inheritance. There only are object constructor functions and the prototype chain. The common convention to differentiate between "regular functions" and "constructor functions" is to capitalize the latter (`Car()` vs `car()`). Using a framework that emulates some of the class syntax from other languages is hurtful to understanding how things work in JS.

Comment: The answers above are providing ways to define classes, which is what I asked for actually..

Comment: No, they don't. They provide syntactic sugar at the cost of obscuring the actual process and at the cost of learning (and introducing dependencies on) whole new frameworks or tool chains. Do you think that's a good trade-off?